# Order values inside a pivot table in openxlsx2

Tags: r, openxlsx2

I´m using openxlsx2 so that I can use the function `wb_add_pivot_table()` but the problem is that the order in which the rows appear, inside the pivot table, isn't in the order I want it to be displayed.

I´ve tried the following:

```
tbl_1 <- tibble(
  var_1 = c("FEBRERO", "SEPTIEMBRE","AGOSTO", "SEPTIEMBRE", "AGOSTO", "FEBRERO", "DICIEMBRE", "DICIEMBRE"),
  var_2 = seq_along(var_1)
) |> 
  mutate(
    var_1 = as.factor(var_1) |> 
      fct_relevel("FEBRERO", "AGOSTO", "SEPTIEMBRE", "DICIEMBRE")
  ) # I want the order of te rows, inside the pivot table, be like this
tbl_1
wb_1 <- wb_workbook() |> 
  wb_add_worksheet() |> 
  wb_add_data(x = tbl_1) 
df <- wb_data(wb_1)
wb_1 |> 
  wb_add_pivot_table(
    x = df,
    rows = "var_1",
    data = "var_2",
    fun = "sum"
  ) |> 
  wb_save("example_1.xlsx")
```

My naive approach, as you see, was to convert the class of the var_1 column to factor, but it didn't work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, this is currently [not possible.](https://github.com/JanMarvin/openxlsx2/blob/04712579c85e007e38aec3a06e31ae54d1e0d24f/R/helper-functions.R#L638) You can create different variables and switch their orders or modify the order manually. (At some point you have to open the file ...). Feel free to open an issue with openxlsx2.

Comment: I see, I update the underlying data for that pivot table every day so i had to order manually the rows each day for my coworkers, that's why I wanted something more automated. But it's okay, Would be nice to have a vignette for pivot tables! ;)  i really like the package btw!

Comment: Thanks! We'll get there, [here are a few lose snippets](https://janmarvin.github.io/ox2-book/chapters/openxlsx2_pivot_tables.html) and sorting should be simple to implement. Still as alternative: you could create a pivot table from some worksheet data and replace the data on the sheet and update the pivot table afterwards. I do this a lot with SAS

Comment: It's now possible with the development branch and will be part of the next release.

Comment: Sounds great! Thanks! Will buy me a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up this question badly.
The problem I really wanted to solve was this:

```
library(tidyverse); library(openxlsx2)

tbl_1 <- tibble(
  var_1 = seq(from = ymd("2023-01-01"),
              to = ymd("2024-03-31"),
              by = "month"),
  var_2 = seq_along(var_1)
) |> 
  uncount(2) |> 
  mutate(
    year = year(var_1),
    month = month(var_1, label = TRUE)
  )
```

With this I wanted the year and month columns be in the column field inside the pivot table. The problem with this is that the month column is not in the proper order, not Ene-Dic:

```
wb_1 <- wb_workbook() |>
  wb_add_worksheet() |>
  wb_add_data(x = tbl_1)
df <- wb_data(wb_1)
wb_1 |>
  wb_add_pivot_table(
    x = df,
    cols = c("year", "month"),
    data = "var_2",
    fun = "sum"
  )
```

This results in: [image]

Now, according to the [docs](https://github.com/JanMarvin/openxlsx2/pull/795), the following should work:

```
wb_1 <- wb_workbook() |> 
  wb_add_worksheet() |> 
  wb_add_data(x = tbl_1) 
df <- wb_data(wb_1)
wb_1 |> 
  wb_add_pivot_table(
    x = df,
    cols = c("year", "month"),
    data = "var_2",
    fun = "sum",
    params = list(
      sort_item = list(month = 12:1)
    )
  )
```

And it does:

[image]

Comment: With release 1.2 it is also possible to sort on character strings. So `month = c('Jan', 'Feb', ..., 'Dic'))` is also possible and might guard against cases with unsorted factor levels.